# Opening Google Calendar event links from within Full Calendar using Magnific Popup

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, magnific-popup

I'm using [Full Calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to pull in Google Calendar information and would like to do something similar to [this](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/fullcalendar-event-details-with-bootstrap-modal/) which populates empty elements in a hidden element when links in the calendar are clicked, and then displays it in a Bootstrap modal window, except with [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) which I'm already using for modals on this particular site.

In the Bootstrap example, the modal is initialised with:

```
$('#modal').modal();
```

but with Magnific Popup, it's initalised on the link you click on instead. So I'm not really sure how to go about combining the two techniques.

So in my HTML, I have:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<div id="calendar-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <h2 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h2>
    <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
    <a id="eventUrl" class="button" rel="external">Event page</a>
</div>
```

and my js:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,basicDay'
    },
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'XXXX',
    eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
        $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
        $('#calendar-popup').magnificPopup({type:'inline'});
    },
    eventSources: [
        …
    ]
});
```

At the moment I'm initialising `magnificPopup` with `#calendar-popup` but that's the target, not the link that's being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach Magnific Popup to the eventRender:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
     //Initialize Magnific Popup Plugin for event info on eventClick
     element.magnificPopup({
          items: {
               // Set the source to the div containing event's data
               src: '#eventContent',
               type: 'inline'
          }
      });
}
```

More info here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Comment: So that means do we have to create separate divs for separate events? Can't it be done dynamically like onclick event?